# Сформируйте массив, содержащий числа, которые являются суммой символов в каждом слове

Tags: java

Дано предложение. Сформируйте массив, содержащий числа, которые являются суммой символов в каждом слове.
сделать нужно на java

Comment: Ну раз нужно, значит нужно.  Только вот Вы забыли написать в чем у Вас проблема возникла. Что пошло не так когда делали задачу?

Answer (score 2):

Сплитишь предложение по пробелу split(" "). Получаешь массив строк. Инициализуешь новый массив чисел, размерностью равной массиву строк. В каждуе ячейку массива с числами заносишь длину каждого элемента в массиве строк. Все.